# What is the SCOTUS's standard of *dangerousness* in decisions of involuntary psychiatric commitment?

Tags: us-constitution, us-supreme-court, mental-health

It seems that the standard of immediacy/imminence of the dangerousness was not ever that well defined by the SCOTUS.

This is the best, most comprehensive reference on the matter that I've been able to find, but I'm hoping that someone familiar with the relevant case law can weigh in.

http://psychrights.org/force_of_law.htm

If someone is nonspecifically or potentially dangerous at some vague, distant, indeteminate point in the future, can they be constitutionally committed to a mental institution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An annotated bibliography of the leading cases in the mental health area from the U.S. Supreme Court are summarized [here](https://mentalillnesspolicy.org/legal/mental-illness-supreme-court.html) and this is a pretty fair summary of the U.S. Supreme Court case law in this area.

Essentially, the specific details of the commitment standard within the bounds established by *O’Connor v. Donaldson*, 422 U.S. 563 (1975) are a question of state law with respect to which some variation is permissible without being dictated precisely by the limitations of the U.S. Constitution. There is also no controlling federal statute that further limits state discretion.

I'll quote entries related to the six controlling U.S. Supreme Court that are pertinent to this question (emphasis mine):

> *O’Connor v. Donaldson*, 422 U.S. 563 (1975). Mentally ill plaintiff was confined without treatment for 15 years. Held: **states cannot
> constitutionally confine, “without more,” a person who is not a danger
> to others or to himself.** The latter category includes the suicidal
> and the “gravely disabled,” who are unable to “avoid the hazards of
> freedom” either alone or with the aid of willing family or friends.
> 422 U.S. at 575 and n.9. As the plaintiff received no treatment, the
> Court expressly reserved the question “whether the provision of
> treatment, standing alone, can ever constitutionally justify
> involuntary confinement or, if it can, how much and what kind of
> treatment would suffice. . . . “ Id. at n.10. The Court has never
> revisited this issue. http://laws.findlaw.com/US/422/563.html
>
> *Addington v. Texas*, 441 U.S. 418 (1979). Plaintiff, who disputed his dangerousness, was indefinitely committed based on a history of mental
> illness, threats, and several in-hospital assaults. Held: **jury
> instruction requiring “clear and convincing evidence” that plaintiff
> required commitment “for his own welfare and protection, or the
> protection of others” was constitutionally adequate.**
>
> *Zinermon v. Burch*, 494 U.S. 113 (1990). Psychotic individual “voluntarily” committed for treatment. Held: **U.S. Constitution
> prohibits “voluntary” commitments where patient is incapable of
> informed consent.** Dualing dicta: On the one hand, wrongly
> characterizes O’Connor v. Donaldson as holding that **“there is no
> basis for confining mentally ill persons involuntarily ‘if they are
> dangerous to no one and can safely live in freedom,’”** 494 U.S. at
> 134. On **the other, accepts without comment a state standard that defines grave disability very loosely, permitting involuntary
> commitment for individuals whose “neglect or refusal to care for
> themselves threatens their well-being,”** Id . (emphasis added).
>
> *Kansas v. Hendricks*, 521 U.S. 346 (1997). Held: civil commitment of pedophile by jury trial immediately following his release from prison
> did not constitute double jeopardy , ex post-facto lawmaking or
> violation of substantive due process, where petitioner admittedly
> posed current danger to children. It was immaterial that pedophile was
> not mentally ill, as **“we have traditionally left to state
> legislatures the task of defining terms of a medical nature that have
> legal significance” and “have never held that the Constitution
> prevents a State from civilly detaining those for whom no treatment is
> available, but who nevertheless pose a danger to others.”**
> **Holding modified in *Kansas v. Crane***, 534 U.S. 407 (2002): **“[T]here must be proof of serious difficulty in controlling behavior. . .viewed in light of such features of the cases as the
> nature of the psychiatric diagnosis, and the severity of the mental
> abnormality itself. . . sufficient to distinguish the dangerous sexual
> offender whose serious mental illness, abnormality, or disorder
> subjects him to civil commitment from the dangerous but typical
> recidivist convicted in an ordinary criminal case. . . . “** 534 U.S.
> at 412-413.
>
> *Sell v U.S*, 539 U.S.166 (2003) Psychotic dentist threatened a witness, refused medications needed to make him competent to stand
> trial for Medicaid fraud, and stalked a nurse while hospitalized.
> Lower courts disagreed whether dentist was dangerous. Supreme Court
> assumed he was not dangerous because of procedural posture, but was
> plainly unhappy about the assumption. Held: **1) courts should first
> consider authorizing medications on alternative grounds, such as
> dangerousness, to avoid the question posed; 2)Eighth Circuit erred in
> holding that medication may be forced solely to force trial
> competence, without considering whether medications would affect
> fairness of trial, obviate an already lengthy confinement, or
> ameliorate future dangerousness.**

Comment: The Addington v Texas case refers to and accepts a standard of “clear and convincing evidence” as “adequate,” but does it bind states to require this standard when committing someone?

Comment: @Timothy It does not bind state to that standard. *Addington* basically establishes that the beyond a reasonable doubt standard necessary for a criminal conviction is not required for a mental health commitment. SCOTUS hasn't ruled on whether preponderance of the evidence is good enough but has repeatedly denied cert from appellants arguing that it was not sufficient.